# AWS S3 Java: doesObjectExist results in 403: FORBIDDEN

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, http-status-code-403

I'm having trouble with my Java program using the AWS SDK to interact with an S3 bucket.

This is the code I use to create an S3 client:

```
public S3StorageManager(S3Config config) throws StorageException {

   BasicAWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(myAccessKey(), mySecretKey());
   AWSStaticCredentialsProvider provider = new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials);

   this.s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder
        .standard()
        .withCredentials(provider)
        .withRegion(myRegion)
        .build();
```

When I try to download a file, before starting the download I check wether the file exists or not with:

```
s3Client.doesObjectExists(bucketName, objectName);
```

This is where I get 403: FORBIDDEN.
The weird thing is this problem is raised only when I try to perform an object existence check before performing uploads in the same session.
In other words, after initializing the s3Client:
 - if I first try to check if an object exists, it raises the FORBIDDEN problem;
 - if I first perform file upload, it works fine and after that any object existence check works fine as well;

Here is my stacktrace:

```
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Forbidden (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: 403 Forbidden; Reques
t ID: A23BB805491E411F)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1588) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.
11.128.jar:?]
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1258) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11
.128.jar:?]
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1030) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.128
.jar:?]
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:742) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.128.jar:
?]
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:716) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.1
28.jar:?]
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:699) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.128.jar:?]
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:667) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.128.jar
:?]
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:649) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.1
1.128.jar:?]
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:513) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.128.jar:?]
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4169) ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.128.jar:?]
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4116) ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.128.jar:?]
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObjectMetadata(AmazonS3Client.java:1237) ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.128.jar:?]
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObjectMetadata(AmazonS3Client.java:1213) ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.128.jar:?]
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.doesObjectExist(AmazonS3Client.java:1272) ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.128.jar:?]
```

Another weird thing is that all these problems started when I moved my Java program an EC2 remote machine.
If I execute it on my local machine, the S3 interaction works fine.
However I don't think the problem depends on the IAM roles, since I use the AWSStaticCredentialsProvider.

Comment: I am pretty sure this is issue with your "credential file" accessibility (those myaccesskey() methods), just to prove, replace these with real accesskey & security key.

Comment: I've checked with provider.getCredentials() after creating the AWSStaticCredentialsProvider, and it returns the correct credentials...
So I guess those methods are correct (apart from their horrible, temporary name :P )

Comment: When you change the order, PUT and then check existence, does that work fine on EC2? If so, we can conclude that NOT a policy issue. Can we check your full code and what version of aws-sdk you are using?

Comment: I've run into the same problem.  Did you ever find a solution?  (I'm using aws-java-sdk 1.11.170.)

Comment: Hi @FullTimeCoderPartTimeSysAdmin.
Unfortunately the only solution I have found so far is to upload an empty file at server boot and immediately remove it.
After that, all other S3 interactions can be performed.
It's an ugly gimmick but it kinda works.

Answer (score 4):

Your credentials may be correct, but you will still get FORBIDDEN if you do not set the correct IAM polices. To check for objects in s3 you need the following:

```
{
    "Version":"2012-10-17",
    "Statement":[
        {
            "Effect":"Allow",
            "Action":[
            "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket"]
        },
        {
            "Effect":"Allow",
            "Action":[
            "s3:GetObject"
            ],
          "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This works for me only with "Resource":["*"] for "s3:ListBucket" action. (The key here is "s3:ListBucket" action.)

Comment: the Resource for ListBucket needs to be the bucket, not the files, i.e. no "/*" at the end.

Comment: @Iznt thanks, that edit has been made, hopefully SO will show it soon

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the date time is set correctly on the machine you  are making the request from, otherwise you will get a 403.

Comment: I'm using Docker on Windows and often experience a clock drift when my laptop comes back from sleep. This drove me nuts, thanks for pointing in the right direction!

Answer (score 2):

You need an action "ListBucket" for your bucket but not for the file in your bucket like:
       {
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketName",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }

Answer (score 0):

I really look like an IAM policy issue. 
What is your user's policies on your local machine vs what is your IAM role with which policy(ies)? 
For your EC2 instance, when you create it, create a role with "AmazonS3FullAccess" policy, if it solves the problem you'll remove the useless rights.

Comment: But if it was an IAM policy issue, why whould it "magically" disappear after I perform an upload? :/