# AWS S3 getObjectExist() returns 403 Forbidden

Tags: amazon-s3, http-status-code-403

So this question I answered myself. Add this piece of json to your Policy:

```
    {
        "Sid": "AllowGetObjectExist",
        "Resource": ["*"],
        "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
        "Effect": "Allow"
    }
```

(It assumes you already have "s3:GetObject" action with another "Sid" in your policy.)

Comment: Almost the same as on this page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44256527/aws-s3-java-doesobjectexist-results-in-403-forbidden. The page contains also the right answer. I would delete my question if I had no answer already.

Comment: Note that if doesObjectExist needs `s3:ListBucket` then you're paying more $ for each request than if you just do getObjectMetadata and catch the exception if the object isn't there.  Not quite sure why that method is even a thing.  Seems wasteful and inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add s3:GetObject action as the method tries to "get object" instead of finding its name on the list.

Comment: I assumed that "s3:GetObject" action already exists in the policy. But only this action doesn't allow you to use `getObjectExist()` method, you also need "s3:ListBucket" action. Don't know why.